# How can QOpenGLWidget update not result in paintGL events?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5.4

I'm logging calls to `update()` and `paintGL()`, but somehow, only update happens.  paintGL is called a couple of times and then never again!  How is this possible?  The window is visible and `isVisible()` returns True every time `update()` is called.

Specifically, I converted from `QGLWidget` to `QOpenGLWidget`.  I replaced my calls to `updateGL()` with calls to `update()`, and I replaced passing the format to the constructor with calling `setFormat()`.  I added various calls to `makeCurrent()` where appropriate.  Is there anything I'm missing?

It appears that `QOpenGLWidget` might be broken when it is one of many widgets within a window.

Comment: The window is visible to the user, I assume?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: Hmm. The `isVisible` returns true every time update is called.

Comment: Neil: I mean, if the window is actually visible, i.e. inside the screen and in the foreground.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: Yes, it's visible, but it's full of garbage since paintGL does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `QOpenGLWidget` was in a `QScrollArea`, which was not forwarding `QPaint` events.