# PyQt5 QOpenGLWidget idle issue

Tags: python, qt, qt5, pyqt5

I am working with PyQt5 and have some hard times using QOpenGLWidget. The problem is that the only way to draw anything in QOpenGLWidget is to use its paintGL() method, which seems to be broken. Here's what happens: once the program starts the widget refreshes itself exactly 4 times and stops. The only way to make it work again is to change the active window (switch it to terminal or anything), then it draws 2 next frames. Switch the window back - get next 2 frames - and so on. Does anyone have a clue what is happening there? Or maybe how to avoid the issue?

Comment: Same thing happens to me, but I don't get extra events when the window switches.  I just get 2 events at the start.  I do get more events if other qt windows are made invisible, etc.

Comment: same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748991/how-can-qopenglwidget-update-not-result-in-paintgl-events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a `BasicTimer` object which is by deafult bound to `QOpenGLWidget.timerEvent()` method. In the `timerEvent` method which runs each timer tick I then call `update()` method for the widget to refresh itself. Here's a code snippet that should give you a general idea:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QOpenGLWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QBasicTimer


class OpenGLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self._timer = QBasicTimer()          # creating timer
        self._timer.start(1000 / 60, self)   # setting up timer ticks to 60 fps

    def paintGL(self):
        pass                                 # some painting code here

    def timerEvent(self, QTimerEvent):
        self.update()                        # refreshing the widget
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this up!   I'm already doing something a lot like that and it wasn't working.  (I have a slot that kicks off a timer, which finally calls `self.update`.)  I verify that it is calling `self.update` and that `update(self)` is being called, but that doesn't seem to lead to any `paintGL` calls.

Comment: Is your `paintGL()` doing anything at all? I mean is it calling at least some first calls until it stops? Anyway what I've found important was to create a `QBasicTimer` because `QTimer` isn't deafultly bound to `timerEvent` and this was a dead end for me. Are you using `QBasicTimer`?